# IntelliJ IDEA: What name of these markers?

Tags: intellij-idea

I don't understand this markers (between line numbers and collapse/expand markers). What words I should to google to find a documentation about it? Thanks.

[image]

updated: It is not a `Gutter`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from Version Control plugin, the definition of colors you can find here: File | Settings | Color scheme | VCS.

Comment: Got it. Thanks you!

Comment: Correct path to settings File | Settings | Color scheme | VCS :)

Answer (score 1):

That area is called the Gutter in IntelliJ speak, so you can search the settings for that term. It's typically used to show file differences when a file is under VCS control (git, svn, etc) but can also have other usages.

Comment: Thanks. I've switch off a Gutter Icons and append image to the post. This is not Gutter Icon. Yes, code is under GIT. What this markers are means? and where are setteings (and documnetation)

Comment: The gutter icons are different from the VCS markup, as streetturtle mentioned in their reply. As you have seen, the icons and VCS highlighting can be disabled independently.